# ShareThis: при AJAX-запросе числа репостов возвращается ошибка CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

Я пытаюсь получить число репостов статей своего сайта в соцсетях через API одного известного сервиса - ShareThis. Это называется у них Social Share Count API. После регистрации в сервисе, заведения домена и установки у себя их скрипта я бы хотел получить данные о репостах через AJAX в формате JSON, но когда я пытаюсь сделать это, то в консоли вылетает ошибка CORS, как будто запросы с моего домена к их сервису через AJAX запрещены. Что с этим делать? Получается, нельзя так использовать их API?

Я полазил в настройках аккаунта - вариантов как-то включить CORS не нашел. Документация на сайте дана в простом и сжатом очень варианте и то, как работать с их сервисом через AJAX, не указано. Также нигде особо эта тема не обсуждается в инете, хотя сервис вроде популярный. Конечно, можно через CURL получать эту инфу, но хотелось бы через AJAX на стороне клиента. Кто с таким сталкивался?

Comment: Сталкивались скорее всего все. Это политика безопасности и никак вы это не обойдете, кроме как делать запрос с сервера и его использовать как проски

Comment: да, я так и понял уже :( Обойти - я имел в виду, может я что-то упустил, не нашел в документации/настройках и как-то можно настроить, чтобы принимались AJAX запросы с моего домена. Они как-то неудобно сделали - отдают json, но забрать его запросом из браузера пользователя нельзя( Чем это объяснить? Страхуются от того, что на клиентах будут отправлять по 100000 запросов и они не смогут оперативно банить IP, в то время как в варианте с прокси на моём сервере достаточно будет забанить только меня если что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроссдоменные запросы запрещены браузером по умолчанию по причине безопасности. Чтобы запрос прошел, сервер должен вернуть определенные заголовки в ответе. В связи с этим есть 2 способа решения:

1. Попросить сервис ShareThis добавить поддержку кроссдоменных запросов (долго и маловероятно)
2. Сделать проксирование через свой сервер. С сайта отправлять AJAX запрос на свой сервер, а с сервера уже обращаться к Social Share Count API.